# Is there a Python ebXML client?

Tags: python, ebxml

I am trying to use a remote web service with an ebXML/SOAP interface from my python application and am hitting a wall about how to best accomplish it.

So far, what I can find are lots of Java interface bindings but none for Python.

Do I have to start my project over in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look too hopeful at http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ebXML&submit=search

Do you know if there is a C library?